# How to Solve this Complex Integral

Tags: contour-integration, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

The following integral

$$\frac{2\pi}{ir}\int_{0}^{\infty}ke^{-i\omega_kt}(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr})dk$$

arises in finding the probability amplitude: $\langle x|e^{-i\hat{H}t}|x=0\rangle$. Here $\vec{x} = r\hat{z}$; $k$ is the angular wave number; $\omega_k = \sqrt{m^2+k^2}$, and $m$ is the mass of the particle

Kindly point me to some web resources or some textbook where I could learn to solve/decipher this integral; or why it can or cannot be solved and its consequences.

Comment: Well one way or the other you'll need some kind of regularization, and it seems like there is more than one way to do it here. Not sure if they would turn out differently without trying it.

Comment: Note.  $(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr})/i = 2\sin(kr)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Expand the parenthesis, so you get two integrals
2. The first integral is $$\int_0^\infty ke^{-i\omega_k t}e^{ikr}dk$$ See how it is related to  $$\frac{d}{dr}\int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega_k t}e^{ikr}dk$$
3. Apply a similar procedure for the second integral